# grouping by values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes A and B. Both have same structure(row count, column count, column names and indexes). A is filled with data, and B contains flags(True or False) corresponding to the data in A. I want to create another dataframe C which has values of A whenever the corresponding flag in B is True. How should i go about the same. I believe i have to use some sort of a group by but I am a complete newbee in python/pandas.

Comment: show us a sample of A and B please, we can't have a clear idea about your intentions without seeing a sample. and also give the corresponding desired output

Comment: This sounds like a `merge` or `join` operation, not necessarily `groupby`, but like commenter said, post sample data and whatever code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>A = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[2,3,4,5],'col2':['a','b','c','d']})
>>A

col1    col2
0   2   a
1   3   b
2   4   c
3   5   d

>>B = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[True, True, False, False],'col2':[False, False,True,True]})
>>B

col1    col2
0   True    False
1   True    False
2   False   True
3   False   True

>>C = A[B]

col1    col2
0   2.0 NaN
1   3.0 NaN
2   NaN c
3   NaN d
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what i needed :D

Comment: no prob! I didn't actually think `A[B]` would work when i tried it :)

Comment: Sure thing, i was asked to wait 5 mins before accepting an answer